# What is the meaning of "every of the sons"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, construction

I read this question on facebook,

> A man and his wife have three sons and **every of the sons** has a sister.
>   How many members are there in the
>   family ?
>   A. 8
>   B. 10
>   C. 6
>   D. 12

I've never heard of the construction of type, *every of the...* What does it mean? Does it mean *each of the...*?

Comment: It's not idiomatic English: we say ***each*** of the sons or *every **one*** of the sons. ... By the way, the answer is 6.

Comment: @StoneyB The phrase "_every of the sons_" is incorrect, right?

Comment: Right, it is incorrect. Or 'Correct, it is wrong'.

Comment: @StoneyB  By the way the answer is 8. Unless mom & pop aren't classed as family. ¦Þ

Comment: @JoeDark Nope. Two parents, three sons, one daughter, who is sister to each of the sons. Gotcha!

Comment: @StoneyB Oh yeah. I are thick me innit. lol

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @JoeDark you said, "_...I are..._". When do we use _are_ with _I_ in English?

Comment: @user31782 We don't, I was satirically emphasizing my own stupidity at getting the question wrong. ¦Þ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not everything you find on the Internet is authentic or genuine, especially social networking sites like Facebook or Twitter where people take all liberty in writing English. The perfect example is the one that you quoted in your sentence.

As StoneyB says, the idiomatic sentence will be...

> "...and each of the sons/every one of the sons has a sister. How many members are there in the family?"

To confirm the usage of words, I suggest you searching for the news articles on the Internet or [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/)